# Codeception tests fail when using PCOV with --coverage

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage, functional-testing, codeception

I have a problem with my unit/functional tests.
I’m using PHP 7.2, PHPUnit 8.5 and Codeception 4.1.
My tests run perfectly well when running them normally,
but for some reason if I try to generate code coverage for functional or unit tests using PCOV, they immediately stop without any warning or error output.

```
vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept --ansi run unit --phpunit-xml --no-exit --coverage-xml
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.16
Powered by PHPUnit 8.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Test.unit Tests (1080) --------------------
MBP145:prjct patrick.barbosa$
```

When I use xdebug instead of PCOV, I am able to run the tests and generate coverage without running into any problems.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: If it happened with xdebug, I would say that segfault is happening in xdebug. I assume the same thing can happen for pcov too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into a similar problem, I found the solution.

Opcache seems to cause problems when runnning tests with PCOV in PHP 7.2, disabling it fixed the problem and the tests run fine now.